# Bounding absolute difference of logs given a bound of absolute difference

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This problem is for my research.

Suppose $|a - b| < \delta$ and $a > Q^{-1},~ b > Q^{-1}$ for $Q > 0$. Is it true that $|log(a) - log(b)| < \delta Q$?

**What I've tried:**

Doing a Taylor expansion after formulating the problem as $\Big|log \big(1 - \frac{b-a}{a} \big)\Big|$ yields the bound $\delta Q + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\delta^{n}Q^{n}$, which is not as tight a bound as I'd like.

Comment: Hint: Assume $a < b$ for definiteness and look at the rectangle with $(a, log(a))$  at one corner, $(b, log(a))$ at the next corner (both of these are on a line parallel to the x axis) and with a diagonal line that's tangent to the curve at $(a, log(a))$. What can you say about the length of the vertical side of the rectangle?

Comment: Would the mean value theorem be useful here?

Comment: A simple application of the mean value theorem …

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to NickD for the answer in the comments. The hint was:

Assume $a < b$ for definiteness and look at the rectangle with $(a, log(a))$ at one corner, (b, log(a)) at the next corner (both of these are on a line parallel to the x axis) and with a diagonal line that's tangent to the curve at (a, log(a)). What can you say about the length of the vertical side of the rectangle?

The answer is that this length is upper bounded by $\delta Q$. However, this length is always greater than $log(b) - log(a)$.